# How the equation is derived using geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, markov-chains

I need to know how equation (3.7) is derived from equation (3.6). I contacted the authors and they said "expression inside parenthesis is the summation geometric sequence with ratio of (p1/p2)." In my answer I am getting the same term without addition of 1 in the term. How this 1 comes here. Can someone kindly write the steps. Thanks in advance
[image: Steady state distribution]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently (3.6) is valid only for $n\ge 1$, so we have

$$\begin{align*}
1&=\pi_0+\sum_{n\ge 1}\pi_n\\
&=\pi_0+\pi_0\left(\frac{\alpha}{p_2}\right)\sum_{n\ge 1}\left(\frac{p_1}{p_2}\right)^{n-1}\\
&=\pi_0+\pi_0\left(\frac{\alpha}{p_2}\right)\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac{p_1}{p_2}\right)^n\\
&=\pi_0+\pi_0\left(\frac{\alpha}{p_2}\right)\frac1{1-\frac{p_1}{p_2}}\\
&=\pi_0+\pi_0\left(\frac{\alpha}{p_2}\right)\frac{p_2}{p_2-p_1}\\
&=\pi_0\left(1+\frac{\alpha}{p_2}\cdot\frac{p_2}{p_2-p_1}\right)\;,
\end{align*}$$

and the result follows.

Comment: Thanks, so it is alpha/P2 ??? (may be typo?)

Comment: @Osman: That was my typo, but I’ve fixed it now: $\alpha/p_2$ is correct.

Comment: Thank you for such a nice answer. May God bless you.

Comment: @Osman: You’re very welcome; the best of fortune to you.

Comment: Brian, i just want to clear my head on one thing. I understood the first line of solution. In second line, how we are adding \pi_0 to the right hand side of equation. Secondly in summation, if the end term is infinity (or infinity-1), is it same to start with index 0 or 1? I am sorry for this question, i really need to improve my basics.

Comment: Ok, i understood like this. We add Pi_0 on both sides of Eq 3.6. Then we apply the summation on both sides, such that the left hand side should be 1, so we start with n=1, similarly we start with n=1 on right hand side. So I am clear in the first of the two queries.

Comment: I also got answer of my second query. As both cases are having same first term, so it doesn't matter to reach infinity or infinity-1, its same. Thanks for your reply again. I learned maths.

Comment: @Osman: Just to make sure: (1) I’ve separated the $\pi_0$ term from the rest. (2) Going from $\sum_{n\ge 1}x^{n-1}$ to $\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n$ can be thought of like this: first let $k=n-1$, so that $n=k+1$, and $\sum_{n\ge 1}x^{n-1}=\sum_{k+1\ge 1}x^k=\sum_{k\ge 0}x^k$, and then change the name of the index variable back to $n$.